# Add outdoor lighting under stacked porch

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I recently purchased a new home and have been replacing the interior and some exterior lights to a color I prefer.

My home has a stacked porch. It's constructed in a way where it's open so when it rains, water will drip down. It looks like decking put together perpendicularly with joust to fasten.

As for the lights, I noticed that they have been pooling with rain. Probably because of the mounting holes and other openings dripping in. I disassembled and looked up the model and luckily it's rated for wet. Regardless, I'm looking to replaced the existing disk lights with something else. But I'm not sure what my options are. It seems like the wet rated fixtures from Home Depot would pool up with water too. Only one fixture has some sort of top disk that mounts to the junction box, which could possibly prevent rain from seeping in.

What are my options as far as light fixtures or possibly sealing the openings around junction boxes?

Here are a couple pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those pictures show such a serious ground fault that my computer's GFCI tripped just from looking at them!